# Dark Mode override event listener

Tags: jquery

In this `darkmode` code I want to be able to detect changes in the system appearance (dark, light, auto) and set the `mode` in `localStorage` **unless** the user clicks the button to manually override the `mode`.

I want to have it so that if the user ever clicks the button and changes the `mode`, then keep that decision in `localStorage` until it's cleared.

Currently the `addEventListener` detecting the system settings overrides the `mode` set on `click` but I need it the other way around, where the `click` overrides the `addEventListener`.

https://codepen.io/moofawsaw/pen/rNWxgZL

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function setLight() {
    $("body").removeClass("dark-theme");
    $("body").addClass("light-theme");
  }

  function setDark() {
    $("body").addClass("dark-theme");
    $("body").removeClass("light-theme");
  }
  //check for localStorage, add as browser preference if missing
  if (!localStorage.getItem("mode")) {
    if (window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches) {
      setDark();
    } else {
      setLight();
    }
  }
  //Check the mode on load and style accordingly
  if (localStorage.getItem("mode") == "dark-theme") {
    setDark();
  } else {
    setLight();
  }
  //Check for when system default is changed -> change theme
  window
    .matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)")
    .addEventListener("change", (e) => {
      const newColorScheme = e.matches ? "dark-theme" : "light-theme";
      localStorage.setItem("mode", newColorScheme);
      if (localStorage.getItem("mode") == "dark-theme") {
        setDark();
      } else {
        setLight();
      }
    });

  //add toggle
  $("#toggleTheme").on("click", function() {
    if ($("body").hasClass("dark-theme")) {
      localStorage.setItem("mode", "light-theme");
      setLight();
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem("mode", "dark-theme");
      setDark();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  --font-color: blue;
  --bg-color: white;
}

body.dark-theme {
  --font-color: white;
  --bg-color: black;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  body {
    --font-color: white;
    --bg-color: black;
  }
  body.light-theme {
    --font-color: blue;
    --bg-color: white;
  }
}

body {
  color: var(--font-color);
  background: var(--bg-color);
}

button {
  padding: 0.3rem 0.9rem;
  outline: none;
  color: var(--font-color);
  background: var(--bg-color);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggleTheme">Mode</button>
```

Comment: In the `matchMedia`'s change event handler, check if localStorage is set. If so, *do nothing*. If not, run the appropriate function (but don't set localStorage). If the user clicks the button, *then* set localStorage and call the appropriate function. Add an event listener for page load, and in that, check localStorage. If it's set, call the appropriate function.

Comment: This was the answer.